# Java8 stream - combine the finding of sum, positive result and average result into single step

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to combine the below 3 steps into a single step?

- First steps calculate the total price
- The second step finds the non zero price count
- The third step finds the average

```java
private double calculateTotalBCMMatrixCost(SpecificationEntryRequest specificationEntryRequest) {

        // Finds the total BCM matrix cost
        double totalBcmMatrixCost = specificationEntryRequest.getComponentList().stream()
                .map(ComponentDetail::getStartingMaterialId)
                .map(this::calculateBCMMatrixCostForAnalyte)
                .collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Double::doubleValue));

        // Finds the non zero cost count
        long nonZeroPriceCount = specificationEntryRequest.getComponentList().stream()
                .map(ComponentDetail::getStartingMaterialId)
                .map(this::calculateBCMMatrixCostForAnalyte)
                .filter(price -> price > 0).count();

        // returns the average cost
        return totalBcmMatrixCost / nonZeroPriceCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DoubleSummaryStatistics`:

```
DoubleSummaryStatistics stats = specificationEntryRequest.getComponentList().stream()
    .map(ComponentDetail::getStartingMaterialId)
    .mapToDouble(this::calculateBCMMatrixCostForAnalyte)
    .filter(price -> price > 0)
    .summaryStatistics();
double totalBcmMatrixCost = stats.gtSum ();
long nonZeroPriceCount = stats.getCount ();
double average = stats.getAverage ();
```

Or course, if you only need the average (that's what your method is returning), you can use:

```
return specificationEntryRequest.getComponentList().stream()
    .map(ComponentDetail::getStartingMaterialId)
    .mapToDouble(this::calculateBCMMatrixCostForAnalyte)
    .filter(price -> price > 0)
    .average()
    .orElse(0.0);
```

Comment: @davidxxx the OP wanted to divide the sum by the number of elements > 0. Filtering out 0 valued elements doesn't affect the total sum (since 0s don't contribute to the sum), but it makes sure that the OP gets the desired average. This is assuming there are no negative values. If there are, the OP's decision to divide by the number of >0 values makes little sense.

Comment: Thanks, there is no negative values.